# KVM/QEMU Network "default" NAT Configuration - Guest cannot connect to Host or Internet

Tags: networking, kvm, qemu

In Arch Linux, any guest VM no longer connects while the VM is using any virtual network. This issue pretty much came out of nowhere, as it was working previously, with no changes in any system configurations or KVM/QEMU configurations.

Just to be clear, I cannot communicate from the guest whatsoever. I cannot interact between the host and the guest.

I've found similar posts, however none address the problem I've been having.

**virsh net-dumpxml default**

```xml
<network>
  <name>default</name>
  <uuid>redacted</uuid>
  <forward mode='nat'>
    <nat>
      <port start='1024' end='65535'/>
    </nat>
  </forward>
  <bridge name='virbr0' stp='on' delay='0'/>
  <mac address='52:54:00:aa:32:1d'/>
  <ip address='192.168.122.1' netmask='255.255.255.0'>
    <dhcp>
      <range start='192.168.122.2' end='192.168.122.254'/>
    </dhcp>
  </ip>
</network>
```

**virsh net-list --all**

```bash
 Name      State    Autostart   Persistent
--------------------------------------------
 default   active   yes         yes
```

Inside a Manjaro guest:

**ip a**

```bash
1:  lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
      valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
      valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

2: enp1s0: <BROAD_CAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:e5:a3:92 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::fa0d:bd72:fdba:57c2/64 scope link noprefixroute
      valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Back to host:

**journalctl -b -u libvirtd.service --no-pager**

Note: I took my hostname out.

```bash
Apr 18 05:32:37 hostname systemd[1]: Starting Virtualization daemon...
Apr 18 05:32:37 hostname systemd[1]: Started Virtualization daemon.
Apr 18 05:32:38 hostname dnsmasq[726]: started, version 2.89 cachesize 150
Apr 18 05:32:38 hostname dnsmasq[726]: compile time options: IPv6 GNU-getopt DBus no-UBus i18n IDN2 DHCP DHCPv6 no-Lua TFTP conntrack ipset nftset auth cryptohash DNSSEC loop-detect inotify dumpfile
Apr 18 05:32:38 hostname dnsmasq-dhcp[726]: DHCP, IP range 192.168.122.2 -- 192.168.122.254, lease time 1h
Apr 18 05:32:38 hostname dnsmasq-dhcp[726]: DHCP, sockets bound exclusively to interface virbr0
Apr 18 05:32:38 hostname dnsmasq[726]: reading /etc/resolv.conf
Apr 18 05:32:38 hostname dnsmasq[726]: using nameserver 68.105.28.11#53
Apr 18 05:32:38 hostname dnsmasq[726]: using nameserver 68.105.29.11#53
Apr 18 05:32:38 hostname dnsmasq[726]: using nameserver 68.105.28.12#53
Apr 18 05:32:38 hostname dnsmasq[726]: read /etc/hosts - 0 names
Apr 18 05:32:38 hostname dnsmasq[726]: read /var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/default.addnhosts - 0 names
Apr 18 05:32:38 hostname dnsmasq-dhcp[726]: read /var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/default.hostsfile
Apr 18 05:32:41 hostname dnsmasq[726]: reading /etc/resolv.conf
Apr 18 05:32:41 hostname dnsmasq[726]: using nameserver 68.105.28.11#53
Apr 18 05:32:41 hostname dnsmasq[726]: using nameserver 68.105.29.11#53
Apr 18 05:32:41 hostname dnsmasq[726]: using nameserver 68.105.28.12#53
Apr 18 05:32:43 hostname dnsmasq[726]: reading /etc/resolv.conf
Apr 18 05:32:43 hostname dnsmasq[726]: using nameserver 100.100.100.100#53
Apr 18 05:32:43 hostname dnsmasq[726]: reading /etc/resolv.conf
Apr 18 05:32:43 hostname dnsmasq[726]: using nameserver 100.100.100.100#53
Apr 18 09:33:08 hostname dnsmasq[726]: reading /etc/resolv.conf
Apr 18 09:33:08 hostname dnsmasq[726]: using nameserver 100.100.100.100#53
Apr 18 09:34:37 hostname systemd[1]: libvirtd.service: Deactivated successfully.
Apr 18 09:34:37 hostname systemd[1]: libvirtd.service: Unit process 726 (dnsmasq) remains running after unit stopped.
Apr 18 09:34:37 hostname systemd[1]: libvirtd.service: Unit process 727 (dnsmasq) remains running after unit stopped.
Apr 18 18:35:25 hostname systemd[1]: libvirtd.service: Found left-over process 726 (dnsmasq) in control group while starting unit. Ignoring.
Apr 18 18:35:25 hostname systemd[1]: This usually indicates unclean termination of a previous run, or service implementation deficiencies.
Apr 18 18:35:25 hostname systemd[1]: libvirtd.service: Found left-over process 727 (dnsmasq) in control group while starting unit. Ignoring.
Apr 18 18:35:25 hostname systemd[1]: This usually indicates unclean termination of a previous run, or service implementation deficiencies.
Apr 18 18:35:25 hostname systemd[1]: Starting Virtualization daemon...
Apr 18 18:35:25 hostname systemd[1]: Started Virtualization daemon.
Apr 18 18:35:26 hostname dnsmasq[726]: read /etc/hosts - 0 names
Apr 18 18:35:26 hostname dnsmasq[726]: read /var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/default.addnhosts - 0 names
Apr 18 18:35:26 hostname dnsmasq-dhcp[726]: read /var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/default.hostsfile
```

**ip a**

```bash
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp7s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 04:42:1a:f0:5e:22 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.68.116/24 brd 192.168.68.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp7s0
       valid_lft 6595sec preferred_lft 6595sec
    inet6 fe80::4da9:ee46:ca10:5ccf/64 scope link noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlp6s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fe:32:0e:58:03:f0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff permaddr 1c:99:57:a4:c3:b5
4: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:aa:32:1d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: tailscale0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1280 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 500
    link/none
    inet 100.92.168.67/32 scope global tailscale0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fd7a:115c:a1e0:ab12:4843:cd96:625c:a843/128 scope global
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::1e59:5071:1cf9:298f/64 scope link stable-privacy
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
    link/ether 02:42:46:7a:60:f7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

**iptables-save**

```bash
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.9 (nf_tables) on Wed Apr 19 08:15:48 2023
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:LIBVIRT_PRT - [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -j LIBVIRT_PRT
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -o virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j CHECKSUM --checksum-fill
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Apr 19 08:15:48 2023
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.9 (nf_tables) on Wed Apr 19 08:15:48 2023
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
:DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 - [0:0]
:DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 - [0:0]
:DOCKER-USER - [0:0]
:LIBVIRT_FWI - [0:0]
:LIBVIRT_FWO - [0:0]
:LIBVIRT_FWX - [0:0]
:LIBVIRT_INP - [0:0]
:LIBVIRT_OUT - [0:0]
:ts-forward - [0:0]
:ts-input - [0:0]
-A INPUT -j ts-input
-A INPUT -j LIBVIRT_INP
-A FORWARD -j ts-forward
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-USER
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j LIBVIRT_FWX
-A FORWARD -j LIBVIRT_FWI
-A FORWARD -j LIBVIRT_FWO
-A OUTPUT -j LIBVIRT_OUT
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o docker0 -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-USER -j RETURN
-A LIBVIRT_FWI -d 192.168.122.0/24 -o virbr0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_FWI -o virbr0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A LIBVIRT_FWO -s 192.168.122.0/24 -i virbr0 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_FWO -i virbr0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A LIBVIRT_FWX -i virbr0 -o virbr0 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_INP -i virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_INP -i virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_INP -i virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_INP -i virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_OUT -o virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_OUT -o virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_OUT -o virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_OUT -o virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 68 -j ACCEPT
-A ts-forward -i tailscale0 -j MARK --set-xmark 0x40000/0xff0000
-A ts-forward -m mark --mark 0x40000/0xff0000 -j ACCEPT
-A ts-forward -s 100.64.0.0/10 -o tailscale0 -j DROP
-A ts-forward -o tailscale0 -j ACCEPT
-A ts-input -s 100.92.168.67/32 -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A ts-input -s 100.115.92.0/23 ! -i tailscale0 -j RETURN
-A ts-input -s 100.64.0.0/10 ! -i tailscale0 -j DROP
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Apr 19 08:15:48 2023
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.9 (nf_tables) on Wed Apr 19 08:15:48 2023
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
:LIBVIRT_PRT - [0:0]
:ts-postrouting - [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A OUTPUT ! -d 127.0.0.0/8 -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A POSTROUTING -j ts-postrouting
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.0/16 ! -o docker0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -j LIBVIRT_PRT
-A DOCKER -i docker0 -j RETURN
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.122.0/24 -d 224.0.0.0/24 -j RETURN
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.122.0/24 -d 255.255.255.255/32 -j RETURN
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -p tcp -j MASQUERADE --to-ports 1024-65535
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -p udp -j MASQUERADE --to-ports 1024-65535
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
-A ts-postrouting -m mark --mark 0x40000/0xff0000 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Apr 19 08:15:48 2023
```

**nft list ruleset**

```bash
table inet filter {
        chain input {
                type filter hook input priority filter; policy drop;
                ct state invalid drop comment "early drop of invalid connections"
                ct state { established, related } accept comment "allow tracked connections"
                iifname "lo" accept comment "allow from loopback"
                ip protocol icmp accept comment "allow icmp"
                meta l4proto ipv6-icmp accept comment "allow icmp v6"
                tcp dport 22 accept comment "allow sshd"
                meta pkttype host limit rate 5/second counter packets 10 bytes 4387 reject with icmpx admin-prohibited
                counter packets 134 bytes 101906
        }

        chain forward {
                type filter hook forward priority filter; policy drop;
        }
}
# Warning: table ip filter is managed by iptables-nft, do not touch!
table ip filter {
        chain LIBVIRT_INP {
                iifname "virbr0" udp dport 53 counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
                iifname "virbr0" tcp dport 53 counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
                iifname "virbr0" udp dport 67 counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
                iifname "virbr0" tcp dport 67 counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
        }

        chain INPUT {
                type filter hook input priority filter; policy accept;
                counter packets 5223 bytes 29062872 jump ts-input
                counter packets 5311 bytes 29090912 jump LIBVIRT_INP
        }

        chain LIBVIRT_OUT {
                oifname "virbr0" udp dport 53 counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
                oifname "virbr0" tcp dport 53 counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
                oifname "virbr0" udp dport 68 counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
                oifname "virbr0" tcp dport 68 counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
        }

        chain OUTPUT {
                type filter hook output priority filter; policy accept;
                counter packets 5065 bytes 478957 jump LIBVIRT_OUT
        }

        chain LIBVIRT_FWO {
                iifname "virbr0" ip saddr 192.168.122.0/24 counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
                iifname "virbr0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 xt target "REJECT"
        }

        chain FORWARD {
                type filter hook forward priority filter; policy accept;
                counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump ts-forward
                counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump DOCKER-USER
                counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
                oifname "docker0" xt match "conntrack" counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
                oifname "docker0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump DOCKER
                iifname "docker0" oifname != "docker0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
                iifname "docker0" oifname "docker0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
                counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump LIBVIRT_FWX
                counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump LIBVIRT_FWI
                counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump LIBVIRT_FWO
        }

        chain LIBVIRT_FWI {
                oifname "virbr0" ip daddr 192.168.122.0/24 xt match "conntrack" counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
                oifname "virbr0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 xt target "REJECT"
        }

        chain LIBVIRT_FWX {
                iifname "virbr0" oifname "virbr0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
        }

        chain DOCKER {
        }

        chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 {
                iifname "docker0" oifname != "docker0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
                counter packets 0 bytes 0 return
        }

        chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 {
                oifname "docker0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 drop
                counter packets 0 bytes 0 return
        }

        chain DOCKER-USER {
                counter packets 0 bytes 0 return
        }

        chain ts-input {
                iifname "lo" ip saddr 100.92.168.67 counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
                iifname != "tailscale0" ip saddr 100.115.92.0/23 counter packets 0 bytes 0 return
                iifname != "tailscale0" ip saddr 100.64.0.0/10 counter packets 0 bytes 0 drop
        }

        chain ts-forward {
                iifname "tailscale0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 xt target "MARK"
                meta mark & 0x00ff0000 == 0x00040000 counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
                oifname "tailscale0" ip saddr 100.64.0.0/10 counter packets 0 bytes 0 drop
                oifname "tailscale0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
        }
}
# Warning: table ip nat is managed by iptables-nft, do not touch!
table ip nat {
        chain LIBVIRT_PRT {
                ip saddr 192.168.122.0/24 ip daddr 224.0.0.0/24 counter packets 1 bytes 40 return
                ip saddr 192.168.122.0/24 ip daddr 255.255.255.255 counter packets 0 bytes 0 return
                meta l4proto tcp ip saddr 192.168.122.0/24 ip daddr != 192.168.122.0/24 counter packets 0 bytes 0 xt target "MASQUERADE"
                meta l4proto udp ip saddr 192.168.122.0/24 ip daddr != 192.168.122.0/24 counter packets 0 bytes 0 xt target "MASQUERADE"
                ip saddr 192.168.122.0/24 ip daddr != 192.168.122.0/24 counter packets 0 bytes 0 xt target "MASQUERADE"
        }

        chain POSTROUTING {
                type nat hook postrouting priority srcnat; policy accept;
                counter packets 421 bytes 28614 jump ts-postrouting
                oifname != "docker0" ip saddr 172.17.0.0/16 counter packets 0 bytes 0 xt target "MASQUERADE"
                counter packets 465 bytes 31643 jump LIBVIRT_PRT
        }

        chain DOCKER {
                iifname "docker0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 return
        }

        chain PREROUTING {
                type nat hook prerouting priority dstnat; policy accept;
                xt match "addrtype" counter packets 12 bytes 4499 jump DOCKER
        }

        chain OUTPUT {
                type nat hook output priority -100; policy accept;
                ip daddr != 127.0.0.0/8 xt match "addrtype" counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump DOCKER
        }

        chain ts-postrouting {
                meta mark & 0x00ff0000 == 0x00040000 counter packets 0 bytes 0 xt target "MASQUERADE"
        }
}
# Warning: table ip mangle is managed by iptables-nft, do not touch!
table ip mangle {
        chain LIBVIRT_PRT {
                oifname "virbr0" udp dport 68 counter packets 0 bytes 0 xt target "CHECKSUM"
        }

        chain POSTROUTING {
                type filter hook postrouting priority mangle; policy accept;
                counter packets 5065 bytes 478957 jump LIBVIRT_PRT
        }
}
# Warning: table ip6 filter is managed by iptables-nft, do not touch!
table ip6 filter {
        chain LIBVIRT_INP {
        }

        chain INPUT {
                type filter hook input priority filter; policy accept;
                counter packets 29 bytes 2072 jump ts-input
                counter packets 31 bytes 2340 jump LIBVIRT_INP
        }

        chain LIBVIRT_OUT {
        }

        chain OUTPUT {
                type filter hook output priority filter; policy accept;
                counter packets 102 bytes 8442 jump LIBVIRT_OUT
        }

        chain LIBVIRT_FWO {
        }

        chain FORWARD {
                type filter hook forward priority filter; policy accept;
                counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump ts-forward
                counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump LIBVIRT_FWX
                counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump LIBVIRT_FWI
                counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump LIBVIRT_FWO
        }

        chain LIBVIRT_FWI {
        }

        chain LIBVIRT_FWX {
        }

        chain ts-input {
                iifname "lo" ip6 saddr fd7a:115c:a1e0:ab12:4843:cd96:625c:a843 counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
        }

        chain ts-forward {
                iifname "tailscale0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 xt target "MARK"
                meta mark & 0x00ff0000 == 0x00040000 counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
                oifname "tailscale0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
        }
}
# Warning: table ip6 nat is managed by iptables-nft, do not touch!
table ip6 nat {
        chain LIBVIRT_PRT {
        }

        chain POSTROUTING {
                type nat hook postrouting priority srcnat; policy accept;
                counter packets 24 bytes 2334 jump ts-postrouting
                counter packets 25 bytes 2444 jump LIBVIRT_PRT
        }

        chain ts-postrouting {
                meta mark & 0x00ff0000 == 0x00040000 counter packets 0 bytes 0 xt target "MASQUERADE"
        }
}
table ip6 mangle {
        chain LIBVIRT_PRT {
        }

        chain POSTROUTING {
                type filter hook postrouting priority mangle; policy accept;
                counter packets 102 bytes 8442 jump LIBVIRT_PRT
        }
}
```

Comment: What does `journalctl -b -u libvirtd.service --no-pager` return? Are you seeing any system failures when you boot?

Comment: have you *started* `virbr0`?

Comment: ^^ or is `autostart` enabled for that network?

Comment: virbr0 is started, and autostart is enabled for the network, and there are no errors on boot.

Comment: Can you add this output to your question? In the comments it's impossible to decipher.

Comment: ^^ This should be fixed.

Comment: Hmmm...very similar to mine; not sure what to think. I'm running an Arch-based OS, fully updated as of this morning, and I'm not seeing this.

Comment: Can you add the output of `iptables-save` and `nft list ruleset` on the host? Consider also adding the output of `ip a` on the host.

Comment: ^^Added these commands.

Comment: I will also try removing Tailscale.

Comment: AFAICT it's because your `inet filter` nftables does not allow inbound DHCP traffics. You can try to add/copy necessary rules (the ones in `ip filter/LIBVIRT_INP`) to the `inet filter/chain input` one (which is apparently managed by yourself). (You can also copy the chain and `jump` rule instead.)

Comment: Btw, you'll need to make changes to the rules if you want to make sure that they only allow for ipv4 (when in an `inet` table). IIRC the way is to add `ip protocol` before `tcp`/`udp`.

Comment: Updating the `inet filter/chain input` now allows my guest to get DHCP settings from the host. It seems to be working.